# Golang: Retrieve Nested keys in YAML

Tags: go

This is my `YAML` file:

```
hosts: all
gather_facts: no
remote_user: ubuntu
name: install latest nginx
tasks:
  - name: install the nginx key
    apt_key:
      url: http://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key 
      state: present
    become: yes

  - name:  install aws cli
    command: pip3 install awscli
    become: yes
```

This is my [[image]go](/questions/tagged/go) code:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
    "io/ioutil"
)

type Config struct {
    Hosts        string              `yaml:hosts`
    Gather_facts string              `yaml:gatherfacts`
    Remote_user  string              `yaml:remoteuser`
    Name         string              `yaml:names`
    Tasks        []map[string]string `yaml:tasks`
}

func main() {
    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/path-to-nginx1.yml")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    var config Config
    yaml.Unmarshal(file, &config)
    spew.Dump(config)
}
```

And here is the output:

```
(main.Config) {
 Hosts: (string) (len=3) "all",
 Gather_facts: (string) (len=2) "no",
 Remote_user: (string) (len=6) "ubuntu",
 Name: (string) (len=20) "install latest nginx",
 Tasks: ([]map[string]string) (len=2 cap=2) {
  (map[string]string) (len=2) {
   (string) (len=6) "become": (string) (len=3) "yes",
   (string) (len=4) "name": (string) (len=21) "install the nginx key"
  },
  (map[string]string) (len=3) {
   (string) (len=4) "name": (string) (len=15) "install aws cli",
   (string) (len=7) "command": (string) (len=19) "pip3 install awscli",
   (string) (len=6) "become": (string) (len=3) "yes"
  }
 }
}
```

**QUESTION:** How do I retrieve below keys from my YAML?

```
apt_key:
  url: http://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key 
  state: present
```

*At the moment, my Go parser completely omits above keys from the output.*

Besides, I have many YAML files with varying degree of nesting in them all. Most of then have varying degree of nesting within the file itself. So does my `struct` need to modified in order to address each and every individual key? OR, What is a better [[image]go](/questions/tagged/go) way of dealing with `YAML` files with different level of nesting for each key?

**>>> UPDATE <<< :**

I made some progress by modifying my `Tasks` inside the `struct` as below:

```
type Config struct {
    Hosts        string `yaml:hosts`
    Gather_facts string `yaml:gatherfacts`
    Remote_user  string `yaml:remoteuser`
    Name         string `yaml:names`
    Tasks        []struct {
        Name    string `yaml:name`
        Apt_key struct {
            Url   string `yaml:url`
            State string `yaml:url`
        } `yaml:apt_key`
        Become string `yaml:become`
    }
}
```

Output:

```
(main.Config) {
 Hosts: (string) (len=3) "all",
 Gather_facts: (string) (len=2) "no",
 Remote_user: (string) (len=6) "ubuntu",
 Name: (string) (len=20) "install latest nginx",
 Tasks: ([]struct { Name string "yaml:name"; Apt_key struct { Url string "yaml:url"; State string "yaml:url" } "yaml:apt_key"; Become string "yaml:become" }) (len=2 cap=2) {
  (struct { Name string "yaml:name"; Apt_key struct { Url string "yaml:url"; State string "yaml:url" } "yaml:apt_key"; Become string "yaml:become" }) {
   Name: (string) (len=21) "install the nginx key",
   Apt_key: (struct { Url string "yaml:url"; State string "yaml:url" }) {
    Url: (string) (len=39) "http://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key",
    State: (string) (len=7) "present"
   },
   Become: (string) (len=3) "yes"
  },
  (struct { Name string "yaml:name"; Apt_key struct { Url string "yaml:url"; State string "yaml:url" } "yaml:apt_key"; Become string "yaml:become" }) {
   Name: (string) (len=15) "install aws cli",
   Apt_key: (struct { Url string "yaml:url"; State string "yaml:url" }) {
    Url: (string) "",
    State: (string) ""
   },
   Become: (string) (len=3) "yes"
  }
 }
}
```

So Now I can see the `apt_key` portion which was completely missing earlier. 
However, I do not find the `command` portion which is written in YAML as:

```
      command: pip3 install awscli
```

How do I get that ?

Also, I do not get a nice feeling as I have to declare pretty much each and every key in the `struct` which is OK in this case as my `YAML` is hardly 15 lines long. But this would be ugly and cumbersome if the `YAML` is bigger and longer.
I am sure there must be a better and efficient way in [[image]go](/questions/tagged/go) to deal with `YAML` files.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you already finished everything, you just miss Command part in your Config struct definition. I saw other answers pointed that you have inconsistent data, it's correct but you can fetch them in the same struct, just missing fields will be empty if they are missing in the yaml file.

```
    package main

    import (
        "github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew"
        "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
        "io/ioutil"
    )

    type Config struct {
        Hosts        string `yaml:hosts`
        Gather_facts string `yaml:gatherfacts`
        Remote_user  string `yaml:remoteuser`
        Name         string `yaml:names`
        Tasks        []struct {
            Name    string `yaml:name`
            Apt_key struct {
                Url   string `yaml:url`
                State string `yaml:url`
            } `yaml:apt_key`
            Become string `yaml:become`
            Command string `yaml:command`
        }
    }

    func main() {
        file, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/home/bane/Desktop/go/a.yml")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        var config Config
        yaml.Unmarshal(file, &config)
        // spew.Dump(config)
        spew.Dump(config.Tasks[0])
        spew.Dump(config.Tasks[1])
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. +1. I tried that and found that the `command` is shown empty in the keys where it does not exists. I thought this is wrong way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because you are trying to unmarshal two differents sets :name, apt-key, become and name, command, become using same struct. That is inconsistent.

Comment: Yes. I understand the data is inconsistent. But it is a valid `YAML` and my actual `YAML` is way longer than this with even more inconsistent keys. Could you suggest how can I deal with this.

Comment: Two separate structs can be used

Comment: If you can't restrict only with two struct, you can try to get all the keys and then get the values from those keys

Comment: Thanks. `Two separate structs can be used` && `you can try to get all the keys and then get the values from those keys`. If you could point me to relevant documentation or a quick gist , then it would really helpful. I am learning `go` and find myself searching google most of the time with hardly any luck.

Comment: You can search for any parser, maybe json or xml with examples..They are pretty similar